# how to make a function accessible from html without using window

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I'm writing a small library in a `.js` file. I want to use the class defined in the `.js` file from HTML, and I found that most javascript libraries (e.g. jQuery) will expose it's components using the `window` object provided by the browser.

I am using ES6 and webpack to manage the js libraries, so I want to know is there a way to expose a js function to the browser **without polluting** the `window` object?

for example, I have the following code in a js file:

```
class ChartControl {

    constructor(element) {
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', this.on_mouse_down)
        element.addEventListener('mousemove', this.on_mouse_move)
        element.addEventListener('mouseup', this.on_mouse_up)
        this.element = element
    }

    on_mouse_down(event) {  }

    on_mouse_move(event) {  }

on_mouse_up(event) { }

}
```

And I wang to use the chart in HTML like this :

```
<head>
    <!-- Maybe use some method to import the file here, or load it async i the body below -->

</head>

<body>
    <div id='test'>loading</div>

    <script>
        let a = new KnobControl(document.getElementById('test'))
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Without seeing specific code, I'd say **no**

Comment: Maybe you use imports?

Comment: @Jaromanda X I have add the simple code

Comment: `KnobControl` will not be at all "visible" if you define `ChartControl` instead

Comment: The `window` object is polluted in your example. Every variable visible in the global scope (`KnobControl` in your example) is **always** a part of the `window` object and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Use AMD notation to export the library:

```
define(() => {
    // You library here
    const myLib = {
        foo: 'bar'
    };

    return myLib;
});
```

And then load it using an AMD loader (e.g. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org)) in an HTML code:

```
// Don't forget to include a loader js file
require(['http://url.of/your/lib'], myLib => { // the .js suffix of the URL must be omitted
    alert(myLib.foo);
});
```

The `window` object will be polluted with the `define` and `require` variables, but there are always two variables despite the number of libraries.

Webpack can [automatically convert a code to the AMD notation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#module-definition-systems). Add this to the Webpack configuration file:

```
{
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'amd'
    }
}
```